# Continue PHP Operation After User Exits Early

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel, PHP7, PHP-FPM, APCu and NGINX.

I have an HTML form where a user can upload a file, it connects to Upload.php.

File Process:

1. validate
2. name
3. move from /tmp to /media
4. create thumbnail
5. create database record

Once the PHP script reaches a certain point, how can I have it continue running even if the user exits the upload page early? Or else a rogue file will be left in the directory without a database entry.

```
// Move uploaded file from /tmp to /media
Input::file('file')->move("/var/www/mysite/media", $image);

// Continue even if user exits early
// prevent a file in /media from not having a database record

// Thumbnail creation and other operations here
// May take several seconds

// Save database record
$image = new Gallery();
$image->name = $name;
$image->created_at = $date;
$image->save();
```

Should I use `ignore_user_abort(true)` and wrap the operations in a `while(true)`?

I have other bools in the script such as `$upload = true`. How does the `while(true)` know to represent `ignore_user_about(true)` and not another bool I have set?

Comment: You could consider passing the task off to the queue. Laravel has documentation on how to handle images (base64 encode them). That would be one possibility.

Answer (score 1):

User abort is not an easy thing to catch in PHP... Typically, your script will run until it actually detects the client has baled out by trying to send something back to the browser... In your case, since you are not sending anything back while processing, you should run to completion... even if the user closes the connection... To make sure, you can use the register_shutdown_function() which will be called when PHP shuts down... now be careful, as Laravel has hooks there too... so any timeout will trigger Laravel error first, yours second... However, you can know in that function if it shut down properly or if it aborted...

To play with the function I created a route like this:

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

 Route::get('/abort', function(){
    Log::info('Entering abort route...');
    set_time_limit(5);
    register_shutdown_function(function(){
        Log::info('Entering shutdown function... status: ' . connection_status());
        switch(connection_status()){
            case CONNECTION_ABORTED:
                Log::info('Connection Aborted');
                break;
            case CONNECTION_TIMEOUT:
                echo 'Connection Timeout';
                break;
            default:
                echo 'All ok, user did not abort and function did not time out.';
        }
    });

    while(1){
        echo 'Ping<br />';
    };
});
```

Here you can catch (I used the Laravel logger for the abort... find the log in storage/logs/laravel.log) ...

Now interestingly, if you abort this, you will get an abord call in the shutdown function, because the while(1) echoes 'Ping' to the browser, detecting the connection loss before the time out... however, if you remove the echo in the while and replace it with non buffer work $cnt++; or something, Then even if you abort, you will only get the timeout... the script did not detect the connection closing...

Note that your handler runs after all other handlers...

Also, it runs every time the script shuts down... so even when all is good... as in the default: switch above... naturally, this script will not run to completion because of the while(1)... just remove it if you want to see the normal completion behaviour...

I think this is probably the easiest way to do the clean up... catch it in there and do any clean up you need to...

Hope this helps...

Comment: This may take a while for me to test an integrate.